# Как программно создать Image?

Tags: delphi

У меня приложение без окон, я пытался программно создать Image, у меня не получилось, вот код:

```
Image1:= TImage.Create(Image1.GetParentComponent);
Image1.Width:= Screen.Width;
Image1.Height:= Screen.Height;
Image1.Visible:=False;
EnumWindows(@EnumFunction1,0);
```

Вот здесь ошибка:

```
Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(Image1.ClientRect, SCanvas, SCanvas.ClipRect);
```

Что неправильно?

Comment: > Image1:= TImage.Create(Image1.GetParentComponent);

Вы сами то поняли, что написали? Вы задаете в качестве Owner-а картинки ее собственный ParentComponent да и еще до того как она создана.

Comment: А что мне ещё было делать?! Я знаю что это неправильно, но что мне ещё оставалось делать?! Я создаю Image использую только Application? никаких окон!!! Что делать, как быть???!!!

Comment: Да вы хоть тысячу восклиацтельных знаков поставьте, но решить задачу это не поможет. К тому же, вопрос был задан о том, что не правильно.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню в приложении  без окон, TImage не сделать т.к. оно само окно.
Попробуйте TBitmap или TJPEG

Answer (score 0):

Такая конструкция вполне себе работает:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  ExtCtrls;

{$R *.res}

var Image1: TImage;

begin
  Image1 := TImage.Create(nil);
  Image1.Width := Screen.Width;
  Image1.Height := Screen.Height;
  Image1.Visible := False;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Run;
end.
```